# JsPrettier in Sublime 3 does not single quote className

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, jsprettier

I´m using Sublime Text 3 with JSPrettier to format Javascript and JSX code.

I have the following set in my JSPrettier configuration:

```
// If true, will use single instead of double quotes
"singleQuote": true
```

Even with that, when formatting the code JSPrettier still insists on putting double quote on className and other JSX properties, like:

```
<div className="uxm-details-header-buttons">
```

or

```
<Icon name="refresh" />
```

I really expected everything with single quote, keeping double ones for special cases.

Any hint on how to solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible using just prettier. [Quotes in JSX will always be double and prettier will ignore this setting](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quotes).

If you want to understand the motivation behind this decision, you can read this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1080). The gist of the argument for keeping JSX quotes as double is to enforce a style across the community and the fewer config options the better.

> Any hint on how to solve that ?

You can run your code through [prettier-eslint](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint). This formats your code via prettier, and then passes the result of that to `eslint --fix`. This way you can get the benefits of prettier's superior formatting capabilities, but also benefit from the configuration capabilities of eslint.

Answer (score 1):

In Sublime Text 3 this can be achieved by modifying the user preferences section of the package. (    Preferences > Package Settings > JSPrettier)

```
{
"prettier_options": 
  {
  "singleQuote": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I was doubtful this would work because why would there be a `prettier_options` property within the user settings for the specific `JSPrettier` package (isn't it inferred all these settings are `prettier_options`)?  But it does seem to work for me in Sublime Text version 4121.  Edit:  looking at the default settings more closely, I can see that many of these settings are, in fact, 'nested' within the `prettier_options` property.